# Http status code managed by which part of web?

Tags: http, web, server

While I was studying web programming, I am wondering where HTTP status code come from web (like Apache), was (like Tomcat), or database server (like MySQL).

For example 4xx HTTP status codes are for client side error and 5xx status codes are for server side errors. Are those two HTTP status codes come from web? Or web application server?

Comment: Tomcat and Apache are roughly equivalent for the purposes of this question - they are both web servers. Both of them have the capacity to send a response code back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Since the http protocol itself is *only* relevant and handled by the http server the status codes are also create and sent by that component.

In contrast to that a database server for example has no idea what a http status code even is. It has nothing to do with that protocol layer.

You *can* however tell the http server to send a specific http status from your application logic and that is widely done. REST APIs for example rely on that. An example is a php script that uses the `header()` function. This however only delegates a specific code to the http server which handles the communication.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status codes are *response* codes. That means that client (browser, for example) sends request to the server and server responds with status code and with (or without) response itself.